# Range Slider and Values from MySQL Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have taken a range slider widget and customized it to my needs:

```
$(function () { $inputFrom = $(".js-input-from"),
$inputTo = $(".js-input-to"),

    $("#kalorie").ionRangeSlider({
        hide_min_max: false,
        keyboard: true,
        max_postfix: "+",
        max: 4000,
        min: 500,
        from: 2,
         to: 5,
        type: 'double',
        postfix: "kcal",
        grid: true,
        values: [
    "500", "1000", "1250",
    "1500", "1750",
    "2000", "2250", "2500", "2750", "3000", "3500", "4000" ],
        onStart: updateInputs,
onChange: updateInputs,
onFinish: updateInputs
    });

});
```

What I want to do now is replace **values[]** in it with what I pull from MySQL Database (like 10 different values sorted ASC)

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}  

$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
```

How can i save the output into variable so I can link it in the slider code?

Comment: You have to pass the values in JSON format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get record from database one by one and store all records in one array:

```
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
     $all_values[] = $row2['column_name']; // store all records in one array
}

$final_values = implode(",",$all_values);
```

Then put $final_valuse`variable in your`javascript` code

```
 $("#kalorie").ionRangeSlider({
        hide_min_max: false,
        keyboard: true,
        max_postfix: "+",
        max: 4000,
        min: 500,
        from: 2,
         to: 5,
        type: 'double',
        postfix: "kcal",
        grid: true,
        values: [<?php echo $final_values; ?>], // echo your PHP variable here
        onStart: updateInputs,
onChange: updateInputs,
onFinish: updateInputs
    });
```

Comment: The problem is they have to be inside " " to work - how Can i append it into the each value to make it work?

Comment: Did you try with without double quote?

Comment: yes, the range slider converts into to the one without set values. Generating variable works fine (without " ") which i echo'ed - it's just the problem with getting it inside the range slider js code.

Comment: it's actually in header of the file inside  <script> - I have not yet moved it to seperate file

Comment: You need to used AJAX call for get your values from PHP file.

Comment: you are right! I have put it in the same file and it works like a charm. Thanks for your help, I will move it to another file afterwards and do the AJAX call.